# Too much time to print all possible words that have 4 letters

Tags: c++

I wrote a program that prints all possible words that have 4 letters ,the letters can be in upper case or lower case ,And it took 42 minutes which is long amount of time .`

```
char Something[5]={0,0,0,0};

for(int i=65;i<=122;i++){ //65 is ascii representation of A and 122 for z
    Something[0]=i;
    cout<<Something<<endl;
    for(int j=65;j<=122;j++){
        Something[1]=j;
        cout<<Something<<endl;
        for(int n=65;n<=122;n++){
            Something[2]=n;
             cout<<Something<<endl;
            for(int m=65;m<=122;m++){
                Something[3]=m;
                 cout<<Something<<endl;`
```

So I need to know what takes most of the time in the program .
And how I can make it more Efficient.

Comment: Unrelated, but just write `for (int i = 'A'; i <= 'z'; i++). It saves the unnecessary comment, makes it more clear what you're doing, and works in different encoding

Comment: Your iteration causes - " long amount of time"!!!

Comment: There's over 11 million strings *to print*.  And there in lies the issue.  The console I/O is likely where your program is spending the majority of it's time.  If you removed all your `cout` statements, the program would run several orders of magnitude faster.  Consider writing all your individual numbers to a `sstream`.  Then when the sstream gets to a certain length (e.g. 1M chars), do the cout then or save to file.  The clear the stream and keep looping.

Comment: What about ASCII 91 to 96? They are not English alphabets.

Comment: Incidentally, you can write those loops like `for(int i='A';i<='z';i++)`; notice that they'll print all the symbols between `'Z'` and `'a'` anyway.

Comment: @selbie: that's called "buffering" and it's what all streams do automatically if you don't force flushes with `endl` for no good reason.

Comment: @CinCout yes well in my original code I made an if statement so when the counter reach these symbols the If statement it assign the counter to the next letter so the program skip the symbols .

Comment: Make sure you are compiling with optimization enabled.

Answer (score 6):

We can get rid of the calls to `endl`, use only letters, and simply write out each string as it's complete:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string out = "    ";

    std::string letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                          "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

     for (char f : letters)
         for (char g : letters)
             for (char h : letters)
                 for (char i : letters) {
                     out[0] = f;
                     out[1] = g;
                     out[2] = h;
                     out[3] = i;
                     std::cout << out << '\n';
                 }
}
```

A quick test on my machine (which is rather trailing edge hardware--an AMD A8-7600) shows this running in a little over half a second (with the output directed to a file). Realistically, the time is likely to depend more upon disk speed than CPU speed. It produces about 30 megabytes of output, so on a typical disk with a maximum write speed of 100 megabytes per second (or so) the minimum time would be around a third of a second, regardless of CPU speed (though you might be able to do considerably better with a really fast CPU and an SSD).

Comment: This is far more efficient than my try.

Comment: It may be marginally faster copying into `out[#]` right after each corresponding loop instead than all in the inner loop, or even using straight `out` elements as loop variables (they probably won't be in registers anymore, but the `operator<<` in the inner loop is going to spill every register anyway).

Comment: I've run this solution alongside OPs method and mine. On my machine, while both OPs solution and mine take ~20s, this takes ~13s. Anyone care to explain what is going on here? (Apart from the obvious facts that this loops through only 52 elements while OPs and mine go through 57, and not printing in the outer loops)

Comment: @MatteoItalia: at least in theory, that *could* improve speed a bit--then again, the compiler may easily hoist the repeated assignments out of the inner loops. Or maybe it's just swamped out so thoroughly by the I/O time that it's just lost in the noise. Either way, doesn't seem to make a difference in timing measurements.

Comment: Yep, most probably the slow thing here is now either IO or the iostream overhead. The next noticeable speedup (if it isn't IO bound yet) is probably going to be doing your own buffering in the inner loops (using a preallocated vector and copying the bytes straight in it at the right positions) and flushing it just into the outmost loop (every ~700 KB) using unformatted output functions.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Yeah, especially Windows, you can get quite a bit win by using a big buffer, and writing using `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`, which bypasses nearly the entire I/O subsystem, and essentially just copies directly from your buffer to the disk. In my testing, this usually does I/O right at the disk's theoretical limit. Not nearly as big of a win on Linux though (it does better to start with, for one thing).

Comment: @JerryCoffin: it actually turns out that even on Linux and with plain `ostream::write` the speedup is quite substantial, [I tried it on my machine and I get a 20x over your solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44152600/214671).

Answer (score 2):

Riffing over [*@Jerry Coffin*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44149914/214671) (which is already a big win over OP's solution), I get an extra 20x improvement on my machine:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const char l[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                     "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    // trim away the final NUL
    const char (&letters)[sizeof(l)-1] = (const char (&)[sizeof(l)-1])l;

    std::vector<char> obuf(5*sizeof(letters)*sizeof(letters)*sizeof(letters));

    for (char f : letters) {
        char *out = obuf.data();
        for (char g : letters) {
            for (char h : letters) {
                for (char i : letters) {
                    out[0] = f;
                    out[1] = g;
                    out[2] = h;
                    out[3] = i;
                    out[4] = '\n';
                    out+=5;
                }
            }
        }
        std::cout.write(obuf.data(), obuf.size());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Redirecting to `/dev/null` (*edit*: or to a file on my disk; Linux seems pretty good at IO caching) on my machine Jerry Coffin's answer takes roughly 400 ms, mine takes 20 ms.

This is quite obvious if you think that the inner loop here [is just trivial pointer manipulation](https://godbolt.org/g/ZLmzvB) into a preallocated buffer, without function calls, extra branches and "complicated" stuff that poisons the registers and wastes time (`operator<<` is quite a complicated beast even for `char`s - for no good reason if you ask me). IO (plus stupid iostream overhead) is done just once every ~ 700 KB, so its cost is well amortized.